# Best way to add environment variables to MobaXterm

Tags: unix, environment-variables, xterm

I'm just now setting up MobaXTerm on my local computer and I'm looking to see what is the best way to port over all my environment variables I have on my windows host over to MobaXTerm. The whole goal of this exercise is that I plan to not use command prompt/git bash but instead just use MobaXterm.

For example, if I go to my Command Prompt and type in 'python', I can type Python code in the command line. Now when I do this in MobaXTerm, it says that I don't have it installed. This extends to more applications so I would rather not try and manually install git,python, etc. in my MobaXTerm manually.

I've extracted a list of all environment variables on my Windows host by typing in 'set > paths.txt' in the command prompt, but I want my MobaXTerm command line to reference these when I am using the terminal there. What is the best way to do this? Is it setting it up in a .csrhc?

Edit: I tried changing the settings in MobaXterm to use the Windows PATH environment, and even when I restarted my computer I still haven't gotten it to work

Answer (score 3):

In the "Terminal tab settings" section, so you will find this option in the "Terminal" tab.

Go to MobaXterm global settings window, then click on the "Terminal" tab and check the "Use Windows PATH environment". Note that if you are using a session, you will have to do the same in this session: edit your session, then go to the "Terminal settings" tab and check the "Use Windows PATH" option.

Comment: This does only add the PATH environment variable, but not any others, e.g. PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues while trying to use git. It looks like MobaXterm keeps using his own executables located `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\MobaXterm\slash\etc`, and even recreates them when you delete them.

You can still force MobaXterm to use windows PATH configurated executables by launching `cmd /c yourcommand`, in my case `cmd /c git push`. It will run windows CMD command using your PATH environment variable.

You have to check "Use Windows PATH" on the "Terminal settings" of your MobaXterm session settings in order to works.